# StoreKit Testing In-App Purchases Xcode 12 beta & iOS 13 or below

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, ios14, xcode12

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting_up_storekit_testing_in_xcode

Does anyone have configured testing purchases locally with .storekit files with Xcode 12?
Fetching the products works fine with iOS 14 but with lower iOS versions doesn't work the productsRequest(), return 0 products.

I'm wondering if it's and Xcode bug and wait for the GM to see if works with lower versions or it will only be available from iOS 14 and future versions.

Answer (score 3):

StoreKit testing only works with xCode12+ on iOS14+
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekittest?language=objc